# How to create a python program that adds and subtracts rational numbers

Tags: python

this is my homework:

[image: Homework]

I'm sorry for the long problem and bad screenshot with tiny words. I am new to Python and my teacher doesn't teach so I try to learn from the textbook as much as I can, but this problem is very tricky and I know I did it wrong.

Here is what I did so far:

```
class rational_numbers:

  def add(self, other):

    def __init__ (self, numerator, denominator):

      self.numerator = input(int("Please enter the numerator: "))
      self.denominator = input(int("Please enter the denominator: "))

      numerator = self.numerator * other.denominator + other.numerator * self.denominator

      denominator = self.denominator * other.denominator

  def mul(self, other):

    def __init__ (self, numerator, denominator):

      numerator = self.numerator * other.numerator

      denominator = self.denominator * other.denominator

      def reduce(numerator, denominator):  
        if numerator == 0 : 
          return denominator  
   
        return gcd(b%a, a)
```

I tried to follow the instructions as much as I can and I've done research and attempted to do this for a few days now but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: I'm not very smart or good at python. I appreciate all your help, but I don't know what you mean or how to fix it.

Comment: Why are you using  x (as in `numerator = self.numerator × other.numerator`) - if you want to multiply two values then you need to use `*`
Also in your mul and add methods - why do you have an __init__ method - a class needs ONE __init__ which sets up the class - each method doesn't need one.

Comment: A class initializer has no business using `input()`. `__init__` is already being passed the needed information.

Comment: Also note that your homework says that the class should 'accept' a numerator and denominator, not prompt for them - therefore I would expect them to be passed as paramaters.

Comment: `__init__` shouldn't be inside `__add__` like that. It makes no sense. You add things that already exist. You don't create them in the middle of the addition.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 Can you see my edit please?

Comment: @JohnColeman Can you also see my edit please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your class would be better like this :

```
from math import gcd

class RationalNumber: # Use Camel Case for Class names

   def __init__ (self, numerator, denominator):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator
        red = self.reduce()
        self.numerator = red.numerator
        self.denominator = red.denominator

   def add(self, other):
       numerator = self.numerator * other.denominator + other.numerator * self.denominator
       denominator = self.denominator * other.denominator
       return RationalNumber(numerator, denominator)

   def mul(self, other):
       numerator = self.numerator * other.numerator
       denominator = self.denominator * other.denominator
       return RationalNumber(numerator, denominator)

   def reduce(self):  
       if self.numerator == 0 : 
           return 0

       nd_gcd = gcd(self.denominator%self.numerator,self.numerator)
       if nd_gcd == 1:
          return self

       return RationalNumber(int(self.numerator//nd_gcd),
                          int(self.denominator//nd_gcd))

  half = RationalNumber(1,2)
  quarter = RationalNumber(1,4)
  three_quarters = half.add(quarter)
  print( three_quarters.numerator, three_quarters.denominator)

  three_quarters = three_quarter.reduce()
  print( three_quarters.numerator, three_quarters.denominator)
```

Edit : I have added examples of how to use the class.

Comment: What is `RationNumber` in the next to last line?

Comment: Thank you! This was a huge help!! When I click run, it doesn't do anything, but I'll try to figure out. Thanks! :)

Comment: So I tried and failed. What I did was change ```class RationalNumber:``` to ```class RationalNumber(numerator, denominator):``` and I added ```RationalNumber(2, 3)``` at the bottom of the code, expecting to work but it just gave me an error. ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    class RationalNumber(numerator, denominator):
NameError: name 'numerator' is not defined```

Comment: @anon_misid The class itself doesn't take a numerator or a denominator, though its initializer does. It makes no sense to say that e.g. 5 is the numerator of the class of rational numbers. The set of all rational numbers doesn't have a numerator, though any specific instance of that class will.

Comment: @anon_misid - I have tweaked the code and shown you examples of how to use it. Doing OOP is tricky if you don't fully understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this also,
You can overload operators in python to make things easier.

```py
from math import gcd as compute_gcd

class RationalNumber:
    
    def __init__(self, numerator, denominator):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator
        self._reduce()

    def _reduce(self):
        gcd = compute_gcd(self.numerator, self.denominator)
        self.numerator = int(self.numerator/ gcd)
        self.denominator = int(self.denominator/ gcd)
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        gcd = compute_gcd(self.denominator, other.denominator)
        denominator = int(self.denominator * other.denominator / gcd)
        numerator = int (self.numerator*( other.denominator / gcd ) + other.numerator*( self.denominator / gcd ))
        return  RationalNumber(numerator, denominator)
    
    def __mul__(self, other):
        numerator = self.numerator * other.numerator
        denominator = self.denominator * other.denominator
        return RationalNumber(numerator, denominator)

    def __str__(self):
        return "RationalNumber({}/{})".format(self.numerator, self.denominator)


f1 = RationalNumber(3, 4)
f2 = RationalNumber(2, 4)

f3 = f1 + f2
f4 = f1 * f2

print(f1)
print(f2)
print(f3)
print(f4)
```

Read about operator overloading here,
[Article about operator overloading](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operator-overloading)
Also python has `Franctions` module for this,
[Python3 Docs : Fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html)

Thanks!

Comment: The requested home work says to use add and mul (not dunder functions)

Comment: add the __str__ method is a nice touch - I would have used f strings though :-)

Comment: Yeah @TonySuffolk66 , I posted this to tell that operator overloading may be better for this kind of implementations. Specially, for other people who reading this question. Thanks!